# How to build a templated link?

Tags: spring-hateoas

I have a method with a request parameter and I'm trying to link to this method from another resource. I want the link to be something like this:

```
"rel":{
  "href":".../resources{?param}",
  "templated":true     
}
```

I tried the following without success:

```
//First attempt
resources.add(linkTo(methodOn(Controller.class).method(null)).withRel("rel")       
//Second attempt
resources.add(linkTo(methodOn(Controller.class).method("{parameter}")).withRel("rel")
//Third attempt
resources.add(entityLinks.linkToCollectionResource(LinkedResource.class).withRel("rel");
```

Answer (score 4):

It does work now, you can check the following issue which has been resolved now - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/169.

As you have mentioned above in your first attempt - 
    resources.add(linkTo(methodOn(Controller.class).method(null)).withRel("rel")
should work.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't currently a part of `spring-hateoas`, see [this open bug report](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/169), which suggests adding this functionality to `ControllerLinkBuilder` and [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017037/template-variables-with-controllerlinkbuilder) which has an answer with a custom implementation for doing this.